# jQuery Cycle2 doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm using Cycle2 (2.1.5) jQuery plugin with jQuery 1.8.3. Now I load these two cycle2's files:

```
jquery.cycle2.min.js
jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js
```

I'm using this HTML code:

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow vertical" id="cycle-1" style="float: right;"
    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible="2"
    data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true"
    data-cycle-slides="li"
    data-cycle-speed="1000"
>
    <li>blabla 1</li>
    <li>blabla 2</li>
    <li>blabla 3</li>
    <li>blabla 4</li>
</ul>
```

Everythings loaded fine, no error messages, but the slideshow doesn't start. Is there any trick to start it automatically?

Comment: Can you post your js code please?

Comment: there is no js code, just load js files... and in the console log I see the cycle2 is loaded, initialized and paramteres set up is ok. But no any js code.

Comment: @netdjw I removed the `data-cycle-timeout="0"` and it works just fine - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52RHm/)

Comment: send this as answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `data-cycle-timeout="0"` and it will work - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52RHm/)

`data-cycle-timeout="xy"` - The time between slide transitions in milliseconds - [reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#timeout)